# curl: (7) Failed to connect to port 80, and 443

Tags: curl, buildroot

Hello I am trying to curl from a server using this command from my STM32MP1

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":"2","timestamp":"200","data":"100"}' https://dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/boxtronic-devices/2/data/
```

but I am getting

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com port 443: No route to host
```

vi `/etc/hosts/`  gives me:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       buildroot
```

How can I do that.
Thank you

Comment: Can you resolve the domain with `dig` or `nslookup`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry :/ can you tell me how precisely ?

Comment: It worked after desabling Ethernet Link ...